# Convert string (2015-Q1) to date (2015-03-31) in python

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a pandas dataframe, where one column contains a string for the year and quarter in the following format: `2015-Q1`

**My Question**: ​How do I convert this into last day of the quarter i.e. `2015-03-31`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
pd.to_datetime(s).apply(lambda x : pd.Period(x, freq='Q').end_time)
Out[252]: 
0   2015-03-31
1   2015-03-31
2   2015-03-31
3   2015-03-31
4   2015-03-31
5   2015-03-31
6   2015-03-31
7   2015-03-31
8   2015-03-31
9   2015-03-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Not sure if it's faster, but also `pd.to_datetime(s).dt.to_period('Q').dt.end_time`

Comment: @user3483203 I think your method is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

You can write up a function under the assumption that every quarter ends at the same date (which is true for all months that are involved at the end of the quarter). Then you can apply this function to all entries that need to be changed.

```
def string_concatenation(name):
    data = name.split("-")
    if data[1] == "Q1":
        return_value = data[0] + "-03-31"
    elif data[1] == "Q2":
        return_value = data[0] + "-06-30"
    elif data[1] == "Q3":
        return_value = data[0] + "-09-30"
    elif data[1] == "Q4":
        return_value = data[0] + "-12-31"

    return return_value

# returns "2015-09-30"
print(string_concatenation("2015-Q3"))
```